# How do I get a percentile from a list in CSharp?

Tags: c#, percentile

I'm creating a program where I would like to get the percentile of score x out of a list(List  results). I know that the formula is [(A + (0.5) B) / n] * 100 where 'A' = # of scores lower than score x, 'B' = # of scores equal to score x and 'n' = total number of scores.

My problem is, I can't manage to sort the entire list from highest to lowest, and I can't manage to find the number of scores which are equal to x.

Comment: sorry i've understood your question false, so i delete my post

Comment: no, it's not homework... I'm tweaking one of my previous programs (grading system) to see if I could modify it to include percentiles.

Comment: i am looking for the same where did you get this formula??

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like LINQ would be useful to you:

```
int equal = tests.Count(tests => test.Score == x);
int less = tests.Count(tests => test.Score < x);

int percentile = (200 * less + 100 * equal) / (tests.Count * 2);
```

(I've changed the order of division and multiplication and scaled everything by two in order to reduce the impact of integer division.)

Comment: `less.Count()`, `equal.Count()`?

Comment: @Dyppl: Nope, those are integers - I changed the `Where` calls to `Count` calls, which is what I'd previously intended :)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I don't think so... at least not according to the OP's formula.

Comment: @jon Skeet i am looking for the same what is the formula for calculating percentile.???

Comment: @NikhilVC: If this answer doesn't help you and other research hasn't helped you, I suggest you ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is good, but if you need performance (if your datasets are large or if you need to do it a lot of times) or if it really is a homework assignment, it's pretty easy to implement in one pass:

```
int less = 0;
int equal = 0;
foreach (int item in list) {
    if (item < x)
        less++;
    else if (item == x)
        equal++;       
}
var result = (200 * less + 100 * equal) / (list.Count * 2);
```